# I want to know how to efficiently shorten my if else code

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I'm trying to learn how to efficiently shorten codes. It's working already

Here's the codes:

```
System.out.println("Please type the letter in Capital only.");
    


    System.out.println("Enter the jeepney's number");
    number = scan.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("Enter the jeepney's letter");
    letter = scan.next().charAt(0);
    
    
    if(number == 12 && letter == 'A') {
    System.out.println("Your usual location is Carbon");
    }
    else if(number == 12 && letter == 'C') {
    System.out.println("Your usual location is Panganiban");
    }
    else if (number == 12 && letter == 'F') {
        System.out.println("Your usual location is Taboan") ;
        }
    else if (number == 12 && ( letter == 'G' || letter == 'I')) {
        System.out.println("Your usual location is Mabolo"); 
        }
    else if (number == 12 && letter == 'L'){
        System.out.println("Your usual location is Labangon");
        }
    else if ( number == 13 && letter == 'C') {
        System.out.println("Your usul location is Talamban");
        }
    else if(number == 14 && letter == 'D') {
        System.out.println("Your usual location is Capitol");
        }
    else {
        System.out.println("No record in the database");
        }
    
}
}
```

Comment: Questions about optimizing running code is better asked at [codereview.se]

Comment: use a `Map<String, String>` with mappings like `12,A` -> `Carbon`; depending on *database* even 2 maps, first for number, second for letter, like `12` -> `A` -> `Carbon`

Answer (score 1):

I would change the first if into a `if` with nested `switch`

```
  if (number == 12) {
        switch (letter) {
            case 'A':
                System.out.println("Your usual location is Carbon");
                break;
            case 'C':
                System.out.println("Your usual location is Taboan");
                break;
            ;
            case 'F':
                System.out.println("Your usual location is Panganiban");
                break;
            case 'G':
            case 'I':
                System.out.println("Your usual location is Mabolo");
                break;
            case 'L':
                System.out.println("Your usual location is Labangon");
                break;
             default:
                System.out.println("No record in the database");
        }
    }
    else if ( number == 13 && letter == 'C') {
        System.out.println("Your usul location is Talamban");
    }
    else if(number == 14 && letter == 'D') {
        System.out.println("Your usual location is Capitol");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("No record in the database");
    }
```

and maybe put it into a seperate method

```
    if (number == 12) {
        handle12(letter);
    }
    else if ( number == 13 && letter == 'C') {
        System.out.println("Your usul location is Talamban");
    }
    else if(number == 14 && letter == 'D') {
        System.out.println("Your usual location is Capitol");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("No record in the database");
    }

... 
}


public static void handle12(char letter) {
    switch (letter) {
        case 'A':
            System.out.println("Your usual location is Carbon");
            break;
        case 'C':
            System.out.println("Your usual location is Taboan");
            break;
        ;
        case 'F':
            System.out.println("Your usual location is Panganiban");
            break;
        case 'G':
        case 'I':
            System.out.println("Your usual location is Mabolo");
            break;
        case 'L':
            System.out.println("Your usual location is Labangon");
            break;
       default:
           System.out.println("No record in the database");
    }
```

Comment: Your answer is much appreciated. It's great to see multiple options.

Comment: Your code prints nothing when `number=12` and `letter='Z'`.

Comment: @英語は苦手 Thanks for the hint. Have changed my answer